# Open PDF using Google Chrome

Tags: pdf, google-chrome

I like the fact that I can use Google's built in PDF viewer instead of a separate application (Adobe Acrobat). Normally I would open a Finder Window with the PDF and drag it to a tab on Google Chrome but this process becomes two steps if the PDF is to be downloaded first.

I tried changing the default application for PDF using "Get Info" > "Open with", but it does not seem to work properly. I still have to drag a file to a Chrome Tab. I would like to ideally double click to open as well as drag to the Chrome icon in the dock.

Comment: Are you clicking "Change All" after selecting chrome?

Comment: Yep it seems that was it. Wonder why it does not work without that option for a single file.

Comment: I don't get it. What's better about using Chrome than the built-in PDF viewer, preview, or even QuickLook?

Comment: @fzwo Personal preference. Switching tabs instead of switching applications. Chrome is always open my macbook, whereas Preview or Acrobat is not. So I can always pin documents in Chrome.

Comment: @fzwo, security. Chrome provides a kind of sandbox against weaponized PDFs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you click the "Change All" checkbox in the Get Info window.

(Credit for this answer goes to [Lyken](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/6529/lyken). There was just no sense in letting this question masquerade as unanswered any longer.)